# Deleting data from OleDB C#

Tags: c#, oledb

The columns that I have in my DB are `[CusName], [CusNo], [CusAdvance], [TotalAmount], [ID]` and `[CusItem]`. I get the input of the name of the Customer to be deleted from `textBox4.Text`. 
I have modified the code as per what I got from you guys. But still the entries are not being deleted. They still remain inside the DB.

My Code:

```
void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      OleDbConnection delConn = new 
          OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
          Source=C:/NavneethCollection.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;");
      delConn.Open();
      String delQuery = "DELETE FROM NavColl WHERE [CusName]= @CustName";
      OleDbCommand delcmd = new OleDbCommand();
      delcmd.CommandText = delQuery;
      delcmd.Connection = delConn;
      delcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustName", textBox4.Text);
      delcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      MessageBox.Show("Customer has been successfully removed!");
   }
   catch(Exception exc)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Error: "+exc.Message);
   }
}
```

Comment: Your delete should be Delete FROM NavColl WHERE [CusName] = 'some name'. You don't have to specify the columns.

Comment: DELETE with columns works as well with Access. They are simply ignored. It is more probable that there is something wrong in the textbox4 and no record has been deleted. You could try to read the return value of ExecuteNonQuery. If it is zero then the WHERE statement has not found a record to delete

Comment: By the way, the connection string should not be splitted between Data and Source. Any extra spaces should result in an _Installable ISAM not found_ exception

Comment: Hardly a duplicate. Access works also with the column names listed. And the duplicate used has nothing to do with ADO.NET. Please reopen

Comment: The data is not being removed from the DB. I removed the columns and added the parameter @CustName. Still no success.

Comment: I read the return value of ExecuteNonQuery. It shows a zero.

Comment: @Steve When I removed the space between 'Data' and 'Source' in connection string, I got an ISAM exception.

Comment: I mean you need to have just one space. As it is written now you have a newline and a lot of spaces between the two parts (or do you just reformat that connection string to show all of it without scrolling?)

Comment: If the return value of ExecuteNonQuery is zero then you should really try to debug this code. The content of the textBox4 is not what do you expect it to be. The return value means that the command has not found any row to delete with that parameter

Comment: A possible explanation could be the presence of spaces in either the TextBox or in the database field

Answer (score 4):

In your delete command you should use only

```
try
 {
  OleDbConnection delConn = new 
      OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
      Source=C:/NavneethCollection.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;");
  delConn.Open();
  String delQuery = "DELETE FROM NavColl WHERE [CusName]= @CustName";
  OleDbCommand delcmd = new OleDbCommand();
  delcmd.CommandText = delQuery;
  delcmd.Connection = delConn;
  delcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustName", textBox4.Text);
  delcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  MessageBox.Show("Customer has been successfully removed!");
 }
 catch(Exception exc)
 {
  MessageBox.Show("Error: "+exc.Message);
 }
```

Comment: Please provide complete example, for clarity

Comment: I did the modification. But there is no success. I still can't delete the entry. It doesn't show any error, but at the same time, it doesn't delete too.

Comment: Are you sure that your parameter is correct ? I mean, in a query editor, if you type your query SELECT * FROM NavColl WHERE CustName = 'Your Customer name' does it return a ligne ?

Comment: @CoskunOzogul Yeah. It can SELECT but cannot DELETE.

Comment: @CoskunOzogul I got it right bro!!! It was a problem in textBox4. I got it right!!

Comment: :) Nice! I am happy for you!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

*you have to pasa `?` as parameter name instead of `[CusName]`*

```
  String delQuery = "DELETE FROM NavColl WHERE [CusName]= ?";
  OleDbCommand delcmd = new OleDbCommand();
  delcmd.CommandText = delQuery;
  delcmd.Connection = delConn;
  delcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", textBox4.Text);
  delcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: OleDb doesn't use named parameters. It just has the ? placeholder, and has to match up the parameter value based on position/order of the placeholder compared to the order of items in the parameters collection.

Comment: Well, I did the modification. But there's no success. The data is still in the DB. The code doesn't show any error when executed. But at the same time, it doesn't do what it's supposed to. Could you help?

Comment: @JoelCoehoon you`re right it was the way to add a parameter to Sqlcommand not OledbCommand. I fixed it. Thx a lot

Comment: @Hadi No success still. It can't delete. I tried reading the return value of EecuteNonQuery. It shows a 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete rows in Excel with OleDb. You can insert and update rows, but deleting is not allowed. If your application is not running on a server, you could always use Excel interop to delete the row, but not through OleDb.